# Can and how: do you bend a mesh with a skeleton, but then remove the skeleton and have it remain bent?

Tags: modeling, modifiers, pose-mode

Using a tube as an example:

If I make a cylinder and subdivide it into lots of tris,

Then add a skeleton and bend it to make it look more organic.

Is there a way to remove the skeleton afterwards but retain the 3D dimensional distortion?

I ask because I want to model houseplants and this would make my life so much easier if it were possible, with the stems and whatnot.

I also think I may have performed this by accident while rigging my first characters, but since it was on accident I have no idea how to consistently or if I can even: replicate it.

Thank you in advanced for your help.

Also I'm not sure which categories this question belongs in, but I did my best, sorry in advanced

Comment: Go to the armature modifier on your mesh. Press "Apply".

Comment: In other words:   I'm looking for a way to abuse the rigging tools as sculpting tools instead, because they can pretty easily make some pretty gnarly shapes, but then those shapes aren't very useful if there is no way to fundementally bake them into the geometry of the mesh.    I want to take a stick, bend it with a skeleton in pose mode, and then somehow convert it into a primitive, with the new shape, created from the pose, but, without the skeleton, and then use that primitive as a piece in future more complicated models

Comment: Leander, I just saw your comment, this post was near the bottom of a checklist in my head and was added to that checklist about a year and a half ago, when I was playing with blender, I'm pretty sure your solution will work since it sounds about right, but I am informing you that since blender isn't currently open infront of me, it will be between a few hours and a day before I manage to test out the solution to verify it.  But... I will definitely get to it soon, my creative urges have been firing up and I badly want to make something.  I can't wait to test this out, thank you so much!